# How to sort by model methods using ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, arel, ransack

I have implemented the Ransack gem in my rails app and I am using it for searching/sorting on tables.  However, There are a couple areas where I need to sort by integers that are returned from model methods.

From what I have read and researched, in order to accomplish this in Ransack, I must create a ransacker method which basically converts the model method into Arel.  I have no experience with Arel, but have been researching it.

Can anyone help me figure out what Arel I need to use or how best to create a ransacker that will do what I need?

**Model:**

```
    def highest_mileage
        high_mileage = Expense.where("vehicle_id = ? and vehicle_mileage IS NOT NULL", self.id).maximum("vehicle_mileage")
        mileage = (high_mileage.nil? ? 0 : high_mileage)
        return mileage
    end
```

**Index.html.haml:**

```
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th = sort_link(@q, :highest_mileage)
```

---

I have tried a couple different ways to implement a custom ransacker, but due to my lack of Arel knowledge, I am coming up short.  Below is about as far as I have gotten trying to reproduce it.

```
    ransacker :highest_mileage do |parent|
      expense_item = ExpenseItem.arel_table
      a = expense_item.project(expense_item[Arel.star]).where(expense_item[:vehicle_id].eq(parent.table[:vehicle_id]))
```

The code is unfinished, as I am unsure of how to do the next steps in Arel.  And honestly, I am sure that my approach is not correct either.

Any help is appreciated.